# Redirect http and non-www using only mod_alias Redirect, dedup SSL configuration?

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, redirect, sni

This is probably a duplicate but I can't find quite what I'm looking for. I'd like to redirect http and/or non-www to https+www. This is often cited as a canonical example of when to avoid `mod_rewrite`.

My current setup works, using only `mod_alias`' `Redirect`, but requires an extra `VirtualHost` with identical SSL configuration for one case.

Is there any way to simplify this using `Redirect` only? Or would that require `mod_rewrite`? Thanks!

```
# Redirect http with or without www
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

# Redirect https without www
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
  Redirect / https://www.example.com/
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/example/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/example/key.pem
</VirtualHost>

# Final destination
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/example/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/example/key.pem
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, I discovered `mod_macro`. It gets rid of a lot of duplication by letting me write a `Macro` template for the blocks above and reducing my actual `VirtualHost` files to a single `Use` line with variables. Look for examples in the [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_macro.html).